# Outputting a vector of string objects to a file

Tags: c++, string, vector, ofstream

I'm trying to output a vector of string objects to a file. However, my code only
outputs the first two elements of each string.

The piece of code below writes:

> 1
>   1

to a file. Rather then:

> 01-Jul-09
>   01-Jul-10

which is what I need.

```
ofstream file("dates.out");  

vector<string> Test(2); 

Test[0] = "01-Jul-09"; 
Test[1] = "01-Jul-10"; 

for(unsigned int i=0; i<Test.size(); i++)    
     file << Test[i] << endl;

file.close();
```

Is not clear to me what could be going wrong as I have used string objects 
before in similar contexts.

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Is this your exact code?  This code should not yield the output you are saying you see.

Comment: Works for me without modification. Can you post a complete mini-program (`#include`s and all) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Code looks good to me, did you do the proper `#include`'s and such?

Comment: might wanna try putting an @ sign so that special characters are automatically escaped like: Test[1] = @"01-Jul-10";

Comment: Are you using std::vector or your own vector? - +1 to Jordan/Marcelo - post more context.

Comment: @dark-star1: Whatever language you are thinking about, thats not C++.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: I think the `@` thing is for `C#`.

Comment: You might want to verify that you don't have an extraneous typedef.  Use std::vector, std::string, and std::ofstream instead of vector, string, and ofstream.  It seems likely that you are using an unexpected type that happens to have an operator << defined for the stream class.  Wide/Unicode character strings vs. multi-byte/ASCII characters is one possible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already observed, the code appears fine, so:

- Are you looking at the right `dates.out` after your program runs? Did you verify the date/time on the file you're looking at to make sure it isn't previous data?
- Do you have permission to write to the file? Perhaps your program is failing to overwrite existing data.
- Did you show us ALL the important code? Are there any other function calls we need to know about? Does the code in Marcelo/ereOn's answers produce the same problem as in your question?
- Are you sure that you're running the binary you think you are? (PATH issues possibly).

Comment: I figured out what the problem is:

The code is fine. The problem was due to another application (Matlab) which uses the dates.out file and expected a different 
format. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A related issue is that I'm outputing strings like: 

file << "Some Text[^\n]" << endl;  

Now the \n leads to a new line in the file which is not 
what I want - ideally I just want: 

Some Text[\n]

How can I get C++ to treat \n as just part of the string?

Comment: `\\n` will put the text `\n` into the file.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as expected:

```
marcelo@macbookpro-1:~/play$ cat dateout.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream file("dates.out");

  vector<string> Test(2);

  Test[0] = "01-Jul-09";
  Test[1] = "01-Jul-10";

  for(unsigned int i=0; i<Test.size(); i++)
    file << Test[i] << endl;
  file.close();
}
marcelo@macbookpro-1:~/play$ make dateout && ./dateout
g++     dateout.cc   -o dateout
marcelo@macbookpro-1:~/play$ cat dates.out 
01-Jul-09
01-Jul-10
marcelo@macbookpro-1:~/play$
```